# Matlab - Intersection points x-axis with line made with polyval

Tags: matlab, intersection

I used polyfit to find the best fit through my X and Y data.

```
p = polyfit(x,y,4)
```

After that I used `polyval` to make a line with the `polyfit` with other X data

```
a = [-5 : 0.1 : 15]

line = polyval(p,a)
```

When I plot this line and when I look at the data, I see that it has intersections with the x-axis. But there is not an exact `y=0`

My question is, how do I find the (there are 2) intersection points with the x-axis, or atleast the x where y is the closest to 0?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `line` as a variable name, it is a MATLAB function you are shadowing and won't be able to access.

```
p = polyfit(x,y,4);
a = [-5 : 0.1 : 15];
b = polyval(p,a);
```

To get the intersection with the x axis, you are essentially looking for the roots of the polynomial, i.e. when `y=0` and there is a function just for that:

```
r = roots(p);
```